# htaccess rewrite rules conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

www.example.com/category/sub_category/Having problem with the rewririte rules in .htaccess file.

my current .htaccess file looks like this.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ products.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_categories.php?cat=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_details.php?cat=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$  gallery.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm trying create urls like the following.

```
www.example.com/product_name/1
www.example.com/category/sub_category/21
www.example.com/category/sub_category/product_name/233
www.example.com/gallery/872
```

www.example.com/gallery/872 is redirecting to www.example.com/category/sub_category/872 instead of gallery.php?id=872

edit:corrected url from  www.example.com/gallery/872 to www.example.com/category/sub_category/872.

Comment: The example you posted as last line does not make sense. That would mean no redirection at all is done. You probably want to fix that line in your question. (note: there is an `edit` button below your question...)

Comment: @arkascha  sorry about that. I have corrected the links.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense :-) I'd say your issue is that the first rule matches, the last one can never get applied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the first rule matches, the last one can never get applied...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$  gallery.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ products.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_categories.php?cat=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_details.php?cat=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
```

Rule of thumb: *first* the specific exceptions, *then* the more general rules.

The `NC` flag does not make sense if you also specify both, lower and upper case letters in your regex patterns. It is either/or, not and.

(note: I also included the correction @anubhava posted in his answer)

Comment: I reordered the rules the way you guys specified. But, it is still redirecting to product_categories.php page rather than gallery.php.

Comment: You really mean `gallery/872` is rewritten to `product_categories.php`? What are the query parameters after the redirect, and, btw, really _redirected_? Those rules should _never_ redirect, but only rewrite internally...

Comment: I'm getting 872 when I use `echo $id` in  `product_categories.php`

Comment: I am confused, I do not see how that should happen as a result of these rules... any other rules maybe? Somewhere else?

Comment: the other rules are only these two
 `RewriteRule ^main-gallery$  main-gallery.php` 
 `RewriteRule ^main-gallery/$  main-gallery.php`

Comment: I have changed few things with the rewrite rules.
made this `^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$  gallery.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`  to '^gallery/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$  gallery.php?id=$2' for this kind of url `www.example.com/gallery/category/872/` Thanks. I have learned few things about rewrite rules. And also thanks @anubhava

Comment: Great you got a step further. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Your last rule will need regex modification since you're matching `/gallery/872` and your pattern is only matching 1 or more digits.

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ products.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_categories.php?cat=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product_details.php?cat=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Also you need to recorder your rules like I showed above.